# Помогите составить SQL-запрос. Исключение промежутков времени одной таблицы из другой таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется одна таблица times, где есть поле **time**. Заполнена она следующим образом:

```
10:00:00
10:05:00
10:10:00
10:15:00
10:20:00
10:25:00
10:30:00
10:35:00
10:40:00
10:45:00
10:50:00
10:55:00
11:00:00
11:05:00
11:10:00
11:15:00
11:20:00
11:25:00
11:30:00
```

И есть другая таблица events:

```
event_start event_end
10:05:00    10:25:00
10:45:00    11:10:00
```

как составить запрос, чтобы данные из первой таблицы выводились исключая интервалы второй таблицы? 
Пробовал так

```
"SELECT time FROM times WHERE time BETWEEN IN (SELECT event_start FROM events) AND IN (SELECT event_end FROM events)"
```

но результат - ошибка в синтаксисе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывести записи из первой таблицы, для которых отсутствует интервал из второй таблицы?

```
SELECT time FROM times WHERE not exists (select * from events where time BETWEEN event_start AND event_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

BETWEEN работает с интервалом.

Подумайте логически: по какому принципу MySQL должен сформировать интервалы из двух массивов в вашем коде?

Ответ: не умеет такого BETWEEN. IN внутри него использовать нельзя.

Кроме того, у вас event_start больше чем event_end, что тоже не слишком логично.

Попробуйте объединить таблицы: `FROM times LEFT JOIN events ON time >= envent_end AND time <= envent_start`. И дополнительно отфильтровать строки, для которых не нашлось соответствий: `WHERE envent_end IS NULL`.

```
SELECT time FROM times LEFT JOIN events ON time >= envent_end AND time <= envent_start WHERE envent_end IS NULL;
```